# Как подключиться к MYSQL c++?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

Мне надо подключится к базе данных,которая находится на VDS. Подключившись через ssh (linux) установил mysql(все проверенно,все работает).
Пробую подключиться

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>


 
int main()
{
    
    
    MYSQL *conn;
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn,"ip","root","root","test",0,NULL,0);
    if(conn){
        std::cout << "Success!\n";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "ERROR!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка при компиляции: неопределённая ссылка на «mysql_real_connect»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Вы должны указать линковщику пути к .lib файлам библиотеки mysql, а не только .h файл include-ом подключить.

Comment: @V-Mor и как это сделать?

Comment: Чтобы рассказать Вам как это сделать, мне нужно знать: какой компилятор и IDE используете, где располагаются .lib файлы Вашей библиотеки. В папке с библиотекой mysql должна быть подпапка lib. В общем, распишите более подробно про средства сборки Вашей программы и используемую библиотеку. Только в вопросе, пожалуйста, а не в комментарии.